# Navigate to result page once task is complete in JSF2.0 with PrimeFaces3.5

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am doing some time consuming task at server side, which usually takes 3-4minutes. The task started after clicking on run button provided on the page.
From the `<p:commandButton` with `actionListener` I am calling the task, which needs to be complete. The `<p:commandButton` also contains an `action=myBean.showResult();` field but I want the action to be executed only after `actionListener` is finished.

My aim is to navigate to result page once task is complete in JSF2.0 with PrimeFaces3.5.

Comment: actionListener is called before action method, so if you want to navigate to the next view just return the view in your action method. See this post for more info [differences-between-action-and-actionlistener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Comment: @Ravi is right, In short in your action method write down return "nextpage.htm"; to be redirected

Comment: @Jitesh: both are Ravi here :D Anyway, thanks for the info.